# Adding a user to a group by default

Tags: linux, permissions, arch-linux, users, useradd

I have a group that all users on the system share. The group name is common and it is to allow for a universal fileshare for everyone on the machine. How would I make it so that all new users are added to this group by default? [No manual intervention needed on an adduser command]

Comment: What operating system? Remember unix.SE is about any Unix or Unix-like operating system like Solaris, HPUX, Debian/Linux, MacOS/X... Several of those have a adduser command, not all of them do.

Comment: Archlinux operating system

Answer (score 4):

Set `ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS` and `EXTRA_GROUPS` in `/etc/adduser.conf`. From the manpage:

```
   ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS
          Setting this to something other than 0 (the default) will  cause
          adduser  to  add  newly  created non-system users to the list of
          groups defined by EXTRA_GROUPS (below).

   EXTRA_GROUPS
          This is the list of groups that new  non-system  users  will  be
          added  to.  By default, this list is 'dialout cdrom floppy audio
          video plugdev users games'
```

Comment: Which man page are you referencing? I'm not finding this for the `useradd` or `adduser` commands. I'm on Fedora if that matters.

Comment: @sim, `man adduser.conf`

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, don't have that on Fedora either. Is this file a Debian/Ubuntu only thing?

Comment: Turns out the file is called /etc/default/useradd on RHEL distros. It only contains a variable, `GROUP=...` where you can specify the default group you want to have added to new user accts. Untested, but you may be able to give it a list like so: `GROUP=500,600,400`

Comment: Sorry, yeah, this is a Debian thing.